# What does ._ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have come across this while going through underscore js source code.

```
var root = typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self ||
            typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global && global ||
            this ||
            {};

  // Save the previous value of the `_` variable.
  var previousUnderscore = root._;
```

What is that `root._` does here?

Answer (score 2):

*In general*, that block of code will result in `previousUnderscore` refering to the `_` property on `self`, or on `global`, or on `this` (whichever object `root` evaluated to), and said property value may not exist. It's no different from any other property name.

For example, if the first condition passes:

```
typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self
```

then if `self` has a `_` property which contains `'foo'`, then `previousUnderscore` will be assigned that same string, `'foo'`.

```js
const self = {
  _: 'foo'
};
self.self = self;

var root = typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self ||
            typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global && global ||
            this ||
            {};

// Save the previous value of the `_` variable.
var previousUnderscore = root._;
console.log(previousUnderscore, typeof previousUnderscore);
```

If `self` did not have the `_` property, then `previousUnderscore` would be `undefined`.

The exact same logic applies to any other property name, for example:

```js
const self = {
  somePropName: 'foo'
};
self.self = self;

var root = typeof self == 'object' && self.self === self && self ||
            typeof global == 'object' && global.global === global && global ||
            this ||
            {};

// Save the previous value of the `_` variable.
var previousUnderscore = root.somePropName;
console.log(previousUnderscore, typeof previousUnderscore);
```

*In particular*, for underscore.js, what this code is doing is it

(1) determines which object should be used for the `root` variable name

(2) saves the `_` property in that object in the variable name `previousUnderscore`, so that when underscore.js reassigns `root._`, one can then call [`noConflict`](https://underscorejs.org/#noConflict) to

> Give control of the `_` variable back to its previous owner

by running the following line:

```
root._ = previousUnderscore;
```

For example, if you ran underscore.js and *previously* had `_` on the global object (say, Lodash), `_` would then refer to the Underscore object - but if you called `noConflict`, then `_` would refer back to whatever it *originally* referred to (such as Lodash).

```js
// Underscore runs after Lodash, so when the JS here runs initially,
// _ refers to Underscore, but Underscore has saved a reference to the previous _,
// which was Lodash,
// in the variable name previousUnderscore that your question is asking about:


// Underscore function - give _ back to Lodash:
_.noConflict();
// Lodash function:
_.noop()

console.log('done');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: (hint: `_` is [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/)'s jQuery's `$`)

Comment: That's what this library globally binds to. And this code is checking if they will override something else. https://underscorejs.org/, like `noConflict` option.

Comment: So no more window object is available on the previousUnderscore variable? I am trying to understand core concept. Some questions might be dumb but....

Comment: @Nagaraj `window.self` in a browser returns `window` or `self` returns worker's global object. `global` in Node will return the global object, some other env may have other bindings, so as a last resort, `this` from inside an IIFE should be the global object. Now, note that there is a js proposal to implement a [`globalThis`](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-global/#sec-other-properties-of-the-global-object-global) property which would avoid the need for all this check-up.

Comment: @Nagaraj Yeah, the problem is that if the global object's `_` is overwritten by Underscore, that might be undesirable, so `noConflict` uses the `previousUnderscore` variable to save the previous value of `_` in a closure, so that it can be reassigned back to the global object when (if) `noConflict` is called. It's not dumb, the purpose of all this is *not* entirely obvious

Comment: @kaiido and CertainPerformance I have got it thanks for your help.

Note: Loadash cdn used https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js